# Updating AIR application with embedded runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, native

I'm writing a AIR application with an embedded runtime (.app) and am having trouble finding a way to update it. I need to somehow download a new .app off a server and overwrite the existing file, and promptly restart the application. I'm clueless on how I'd achieve this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: https://code.google.com/p/nativeapplicationupdater/

Or, if you only need to update some content that is used by the app, you can just have your app download it using `URLLoader` and store it using `File`, say to `File.applicationStorageDirectory`.